# How can I get uri parameter start by # in API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I set up an API gateway v2 for rest requests and it forwards the request to a lambda function.
It receives callback request from cognito federated authentication `google provider`. The request uri looks like:

`https://my-domain/signup#error_description=Invalid+user+attributes%3A+access_token%3A+Attribute+does+not+exist+in+the+schema.%0Atoken_type%3A+Attribute+does+not+exist+in+the+schema.%0Aexpires_in%3A+Attribute+does+not+exist+in+the+schema.%0A+&error=invalid_request`

you can see that the url parameters are set after hash sign `#`.

In lambda, I don't see the parameters after `#`. If I change the `#` to `?`, everything works well. But this URI is not set by me, instead, it is set by the 3rd party (google) provider. How can I get these paremeters?